# Label from Price at Timestamp Returns Nan

Tags: timestamp, label, nan

From an interactively selected date, I am able to plot a horizonal line.
The status line displays the y-coordinate value.
I wish to add a label at the end of the horizontal line. The code I am using results in an NaN value.

I am using ta.valuewhen to pull the y-coordinate (level) of the horizontal line.

I believe the ta.valuewhen function is at the root of the problem. I've tried several alternatives to solve or replace the use of ta.valuewhen, but to no avail.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Key Date Price", overlay = true)

timestamp = input.time(timestamp("31 Jul 2023 00:00 +0300"), confirm = true, title = "Time of close")

keydate = time >= timestamp and time[1] < timestamp


keydatePrice = ta.valuewhen(keydate, close, 0)

plot(keydatePrice)

var l2 = label.new(bar_index, keydatePrice, text=str.tostring(keydatePrice, '#.##'), style=label.style_label_lower_left, textcolor=color.new(#ffffff, 0))

label.set_xy(l2, bar_index, keydatePrice)
```